# Safety precautions to take while shifting your computer

Tags: security

What are the different safety precautions to be taken when shifting your assembled or disassembled computer. Do I need safety precautions if the computer is to be shifted over a small distance ?

Comment: Laptop, desktop, server?  What kind of computer are we talking about, and what do you mean by "shifted"?

Comment: I am talking about desktop computers , shifted means to move an item/object from one place to another

Comment: Apologies, in U.S. English, "shifted" normally means nudged/turned/moved a very small distance.  You mean basically "relocated".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few more tips: Remove media from optical drives, floppy drives, memory card readers, smart card readers and similar devices. Check that you have disconnected everything. If you are using micro receivers for various wireless devices, make sure that they can fit into whatever package you are going to use. If there is any chance that they won't, disconnect them. And I'm out of generic tips.

Next step is to open computer case and see if there are any loose cables inside. If there are, they probably aren't going to cause damage, but it is definitely safer to secure them. If you can do it in such way that it improves airflow, then thats a plus.

This one should go without saying, but make sure that there aren't any unsecured computer parts inside case. I know a guy who when he was purchasing computer demanded that a traditional full size PC speaker be installed. The case didn't have the slot for traditional PC speakers, so the speaker was just dropped inside. Its magnet prevented it from easily detaching from the bottom of the case, but it would slide from side to side when case was moved.

If you are using liquid cooling, it may be good idea to empty the system. last thing you want would be to have a leak during transport.

Make sure that drives are securely screwed into place. I've seen some cases where for example hard disk drive is held in place only by a single pin. While this is practical when computer is stationary and quick removal is needed, it is definitely safer to use screws during transport.

If you have caps for ports for your computer use them. This way dust wont collect inside them during transport.

It may be smart idea to use case's original box during transport. It will usually come with Styrofoam pads which should prevent damage from minor impacts and bouncing.

Answer (score 5):

1. Always turn it off. :)
2. If the case is open, ground yourself WHILE moving it.  You will pick up static while moving most likely.
3. Avoid any and all jostling, bouncing, impacts, etc.

9 times out of 10 you will have no issues just unplugging it and carrying it, even if it is open.  It's the 10th time you need to be prepared for.  I'm sure others here can tell horror stories.

Answer (score 1):

What about the classic **back it up first**? That's probably the most important. Hardware is (usually) replaceable.