# Moving a Mac Tower Cross-Country

Tags: mac, mac-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prepare desktop for a long-distance move](https://superuser.com/questions/213567/prepare-desktop-for-a-long-distance-move)

I'm located in DC and getting ready to move to San Jose in about 2-3 months.  The computer in question is an old G5 tower, similar in configuration to the current Mac Pro moodels.  I need to take my tower with me for work, so I can't wait to just cart it out on a truck when I bring the rest of my stuff over at a later date.  Can anybody offer advice on the cheapest/safest ways to transport it?  I can figure out the peripherals and all fine, it's just the tower itself that I'm having trouble deciding what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prepare desktop for a long-distance move](http://superuser.com/questions/213567/prepare-desktop-for-a-long-distance-move) Also similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/253709/concerns-about-shipping-a-pc-if-i-move-abroad)

Comment: Buckle it up Shotgun style, with a pillow and a cup of coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure it's backed up. Take out the hard disks and carry them as hand luggage. Then pack the tower in its original packaging and Fedex it.